# i need help useing this code to print arabic words

Tags: python, list, dataframe

i have this code that remove the commas between the 3 locations

```
testdata = "000000,000000,سالم,امعتيق,email@email,1 1 1990,female,en_En,new york,USA ,new yourk,https://www.example.com"

def split(data, cols_before_addr=8, cols_after_addr=1):    
    raw_cols = data.split(',')
    return  raw_cols[:cols_before_addr] \
          + ["\n".join(raw_cols[cols_before_addr:-cols_after_addr])] \
          + raw_cols[-cols_after_addr:]

print(split(testdata))
```

the problem is that i have arabic data and it shows like this

```
'ط³ط§ظ„ظ…', 'ط§ظ…ط¹طھظٹظ‚',
```

instade of this

```
,سالم,امعتيق,
```

plese help

Comment: Nevermind my answer. Your strings aren't even the same bytes. You must have some kind of encoding issue. `'امعتيق'.encode()` is not the same at all as `'ط§ظ…ط¹طھظٹظ'.encode()`. What are you doing to get the second case? Your test code worked for me just fine and display the correct data.

Comment: the data are in text file i'm importing the data from the file and for etch line doing this code

Comment: Do you know the encoding that was used to write the file? If not, then open the file in byte mode and print the bytes here so we can take a look: `print(open(filename, 'rb').readline())`.

Comment: i think its UTF-8 this is what shows in the bytes mode 

b'10000468742111254525,200000282755,\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85,\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xb9\xd8\xaa\xd9\x8a\xd9\x82,None,None,male,ar_AR,None,None,textnon,https://google.com\r\n'

Comment: Yup it is UTF8, you can easily check `b'\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85'.decode('utf8')`. So, I don't know how you have the problem you do. The default open() uses UTF8 automatically. Likewise, I see you copied the string and pasted it here correctly, so you are somehow viewing the characters correctly. I need more details of how you arrived at the error you have. Where did you copy the incorrect text from?

Comment: i got this problem when i used txt file and for loop....

data = open('./data.py','r')
for line in data:
    a = spit(line)
    print(a)

but if i used it on single line with out importing data from file it works

Comment: What? No, I just ran your code and it worked fine for me. It shows the correct characters. Did you copy the incorrect text from spyder? A terminal? An ipython session? Pycharm? If a terminal, which version, does your terminal have UTF8 set in it's settings?

Comment: this is the code on github with the txt file https://github.com/torgodly/test 
try it .. and thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are not opening the file in UTF8. When you run open() it defaults to your computer encoding (set by the OS). Hence, you are not opening the file in UTF8. If you open the file in UTF8, then you should receive the correct characters.

```
x = open('./testdata.txt','r',encoding='utf8').read().split(',')
```

Keep in mind the TERMINAL or EDITOR you use is going to read those bytes and display it differently for you depending on how they handle Arabic. In my pycharm ipython session the bytes are displayed backwards (and lists of the characters are automatically displayed backwards) and are being read from left to right (it also changes how my curser behaves). In a pycharm terminal that starts a python session, the characters are displayed forward and are not reversed. Copying and pasting to this HTML display also causing difficult behavior.

To be clear, it is difficult to trust what your editor, terminal, os, spyder, pycharm, or other application is doing with the underlying bytes. However, if you open the file in byte mode you can always be assured that you are looking at exactly what is written in the file.

```
x = open('./testdata.txt','rb').read().split(b',')
print(x[2].decode('utf8'))
print(x[3].decode('utf8'))
```